# How is called the philosophy which states that molecules determine animal behavior?

Tags: terminology

What is called a philosophy of those who say that all or mostly all human behavior is determined by endorphins or maybe some other biochemical substance?

Is it close to biological determinism?

Comment: It sounds like a species of biological determinism. In fact, it doesn't seem like an improvement on that concept since there's no reason to reduce it endorphins. / As written, this seems like it's off-topic as straight dictionary definition.

Comment: Off topic comment on the off-topic nature of the off topic question:  This clearly should go to EL&U.  They often answer questions about coinage.  But we can only suggest migration to 'meta'.  How do things get moved anywhere else?

Comment: Seems to me like this should have stayed at Philosophy. I for one have no idea which specialized terms are already used to refer to similar views, and likely a philosopher or student of philosophy would know the best-fitting term.

Answer (score 2):

Materialism. Though it's not only endorphines, and not only biochemicals. NaCl has a deep effect on any living tissue, and thus on its owner's behavior.

And the opposite view is one of many different idealisms, which state that are other, non-material entities that exists and influence the world, and that - although never quantified - still persists as the necessary basis for the so dreamed "afterlife".